# How to write content that uses keyword terms which are google stop words

Tags: seo, google

The keywords for our site comprises of words which are google stop words

namely:

```
thank you
```

Is it better to write this as:

```
thank-you
```

or

```
thankyou
```

or does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is smart enough to know that "thank-you" and "thankyou" both mean "thank you". So trying to obfuscate it would be pointless.

Stop words are basically so common that trying to rank pages for them are pretty pointless. I wouldn't be optimistic about attaining rankings for them directly. Instead I would focus on alternative keywords that are synonyms and long tail search terms that use those search terms.

Comment: We target a really niche market, Where we don't target the keywords "thank you" specifically but use them together with variants to build terms targeted at the market. The reason I was interested is that our competitors have the "thankyou" and "thank-you" combination as part of their URL as a category to their products

Comment: That's probably due to automated software that generates the URLs for them based on the page title or headers. That's how wordpress creates its slugs.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the words are stop words?

Stop words have a very specific definition - here's [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words):

> Stop words is the name given to words
>   which are filtered out prior to, or
>   after, processing of natural language
>   data (text).

I can run a Google search for [thank you](http://www.google.com/search?q=thank+you) and get relevant results and when I run a keyword tool analysis I see that the term "thank you" has about 4,090,000 monthly searches - that wouldn't work if Google were filtering these words.

Comment: They might not be stop words but they are treated differently, google doesn't list them in the keywords section in webmaster tools

Comment: @Craig_Angus That would make sense if your site does not rank for the terms - do you see any Google search traffic referrals for the terms? Have you tried switching the query filter from "Queries with more than 10 impressions and clicks" to "All queries" ..?